# Firebase's Realtime Database's `startAt` isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
var database = firebase.database(); //db is empty.

function handler(e, prevChildKey) {
    console.log(e.val());
}

database.ref('user').orderByChild('color').startAt('a').on('value', handler);

database.ref('user').set({
    'ryan': {color: "a"},
    'john': {color: "b"},
    'kirsty': {color: "c"},
});
```

I expect: `{ryan: {color: "a"}}` to be logged to the console. The reason is because I thought `startAt` matches keys whose value starts with `"a"`.

Instead, it logs:

```js
{
 john: {color: "b"},
 kirsty: {color: "c"},
 ryan: {color: "a"}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query in Firebase consists of two steps:

1. You specify what value of each child node to order by, in your case that is the value of `color`. Firebase reads the nodes, and orders them by that value.
2. You then specify where to start returning results, which is at child `a`. Since you don't specify an end condition, Firebase returns all child nodes from the one it starts at.

If you want to implement a **starts with** operation, you'll want to combine `startAt()` with `endAt()`:

```
database.ref('user').orderByChild('color').startAt('a').endAt('a\uf8ff').on('value', handler);
```

The `\uf8ff` in this example is just a character that is far enough at the end of the character set that the result includes all nodes whose `color` value starts **with** `a`.

---

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your callback will need to handle this list, by looping using `DataSnapshot.forEach` to loop over the children:

```
function handler(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e.val());
  });
}

database.ref('user').orderByChild('color').startAt('a').on('value', handler);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not understanding the difference between `startAt('a')` &  `startAt('a').endAt('a\uf8ff')`. I've seen someone use `startAt('a') for a similar task and it worked (29 mins in here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2CtQEXwOPXw)

Comment: As said in my answer you seem to think that `startAt` is a `startsWith` operation, which is isn't. If you don't understand the difference, I recommend first trying the code in my answer and then playing with various values for the `endAt` until it makes sense.

The reason the scenario in the video works is because they startAt the last item in the list.

Comment: Is this true: `orderByChild("color")` orders the people in alphabetical order based on their value for `color`? Then `startAt` finds the person whose `color`'s first character is `"a"` and includes all persons below it (based on this new ordering scheme)?

Comment: Yes, that's how Firebase queries work: you first tell Firebase what index to load (which has the data ordered in a certain way), and then what slice of the data to return.

Comment: Great. Would you mind explaining how `endAt` works (in conjunction with `startAt`)? Then I can implement your solution knowing what it does

Comment: `endAt()` determines where to stop returning data. So: Firebase finds the `startAt()` value and starts returning all nodes from there. It stops returning nodes when it either reaches the end of the list, it reaches the limit you specified, or it finds the value you indicated in `endAt`.